# Save a list of objects to db but if fails one record, continue with jpa spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa

I am trying to save a long list of objects in the database (MS SQL) with repository.save (entity) in a for loop, but I want that if an object fails when inserting, I know because it is missing a field or there is some violation of a key, continue the other objects but without creating a transaction for each object to insert. All in one transaction.
I have seen many posts on stack how to use norollbackon, etc but I always get the error of "" org.springframework.transaction.UnexpectedRollbackException: Transaction silently rolled back because it has been marked as rollback-only "

I want to continue the loop even when an object fails for whatever exception ... is it possible? I don't think there isn't a way ..

I don't want any general rollback if a single object fails, just a rollback of that object but in the same transaction

I leave code:

```
General method in controller has: @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, noRollbackFor = Exception.class)

insert in the loop of objects

try {
                        
    productoService.saveProduct(prodTmp);
                        
}catch(Exception e) {
                        
}

Method productService.saveProduct:

    @Transactional
    public Producto saveProduct(Producto prod) {
    
        return productoRepository.save(prod); 
    }
```

Comment: That's simply not possible, the reason for that is when you try to commit the transaction it will fail at that time.

Comment: Imagine that you have to insert a million products, and when it reaches the last product it fails due to key duplication, are you telling me that all the time you have been doing the process will be worthless for a simple failure in a product? Can spring really not handle this? ...

Because creating a transaction for each product will take a long time and is not viable, and even if you ask the customer for perfect data, they can still fail.

Can't I make when a record fails insert the above and create another new transaction for the remaining products?

Comment: There's nothing special about spring here, once you begin the transaction you need to either commit/rollback at the end of all statements. What you're asking is ignore some statements in between, that's something not supported by database afaik.

Comment: btw thing you want leaves inconsistent db state after all. Imagine that you'd achieve the behaviour you want and what about failed records then? You can write your custom upsert here as well (i.e. insert and update on duplicate key if this is the only case). 
Also I see no trace of mentioning `saveAll` jpa thing, you can try it at last.

Comment: What I want is that the good ones are simply saved and those that fail not, that they skip

Comment: You should not use jpa to save this amount of data. You can use spring-batch for this kind of jobs and skip one item if it fails.

Comment: seriously is not possible?

Comment: Just to add up on @sonus21 comment, *transaction* is a *unit of work*, a single one. So, the underlying framework that manages your transaction expects **binary** result (**OK** or **KO**). This is not whether it is spring on some other framework,

Comment: EBay, Amazon, how works when bulk inserts and fail one? They rollback all? Strange anyways

Comment: I just got it guys hahahahahahahaha, I have the solution!  STATELESS SESSION!